# Display SUM of 2 listed/GROUP BY values using WHERE condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum

I want to add the values of two columns displayed and display as 1 column name.
This is the output I'm getting,

```
ID        Total
Apple     10
RawApple  10
Mango     10
RawMango  10
```

I want the output as

```
ID      Total
Apples   20
Mangoes  20
```

Comment: I'm trying to get this in MSSQL 2017.

Comment: is Apples and mangoes the only two groups you need in the final output

Comment: could there be other 'Apples' and 'Mangoes' as ID apart from the records above?

Comment: Yes, either as (Apples & Mangoes) or (Apple & Mango). I use the below query to display the table.  "select ID, (select count(fruits)) AS Total from market WHERE  group by ID"

Comment: Don't you just love it when someone moves the goal posts and invalidates answers with an edit.

Answer (score 2):

If the issue is removing the first three characters -- if they are "Raw" -- then you can do:

```
select (case when id like 'Raw%' then stuff(id, 1, 3, '') else id end) as id,
       sum(total)
from t
group by (case when id like 'Raw%' then stuff(id, 1, 3, '') else id end);
```

If you want to replace specific values with other values, I would suggest an in-query lookup table:

```
select coalesce(v.new_id, t.id) as id, sum(total)
from t left join
     (values ('RawApple', 'Apple'),
             ('RawMango', 'Mango')
     ) v(id, new_id)
     on t.id = v.id
group by coalesce(v.new_id, t.id);
```

Answer (score 1):

*If* we can assume that the name of the fruit is after the prefix, and the prefix ends with a hyphen (`-`), then we can use `STUFF` to remove the prefix and then aggregate:

```sql
WITH VTE AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES('Apple',10),
                ('Raw-Apple',10),
                ('Mango',10),
                ('Raw-Mango',10))V(ID,Total))
SELECT S.ID,
       SUM(V.Total) AS Total
FROM VTE V
     CROSS APPLY(VALUES(STUFF(V.ID,1,CHARINDEX('-',V.ID),'')))S(ID)
GROUP BY S.ID;
```

Note I don't change the names of the fruits to the plural, as depending on the fruit changes what the plural is. You'll need a dictionary table to store what the plural of the fruit is and then `JOIN to that. So a table that looks like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.FruitPlural (Fruit varchar(20), Plural varchar(20));
INSERT INTO dbo.FruitPlural
VALUES ('Apple','Apples'),
       ('Mango','Mangoes'),
       ('Strawberry','Strawberries'),
       ...;
```

*Note, this answer was invalidated due to the OP moving the goal posts due to the sample data not being representative of their actual data, however, I am leaving here as it may help future users.*

Comment: there is no HYPHEN in the ID values.. I would like to display as Apple if any type of apple listed in ID's either ( Apple, rawApple, GreeApple) like this

Comment: *"there is no HYPHEN in the ID values"* Yes, there is: `'Raw-Apple'` and `'Raw-Mango'`. There is a hyphen after `'Raw'` in both those strings. That `-` character is a hyphen.

Comment: And you have invalidated my answer, @Vignesh ... **Representative** sample data is important. But you can just use `REPLACE` here instead.